# How can I display a translation of a database column name as a table heading in a view, Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, rails-i18n

I have a model called `User` with an attribute called `current_sign_in_at`. In my **en.yml** file I have the display name as such…

```
en-GB:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        current_sign_in_at: "Last sign-in"
```

…which allows me to display the desired form label ("Last sign-in") using `= f.label :current_sign_in_at`.

But how can I use this same translation for a table header, i.e. not in a form?

```
%th= :current_sign_in_at
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the static method "human_attribute_name", [See the doc here on API dock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/human_attribute_name/class)

In your case:

```
%th= User.human_attribute_name :current_sign_in_at
```

(use `User.human_name` to display the model name translated with I18n in `en.activerecord.models.user`)

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's perfect! Just what I was hoping for. Many thanks @MrYoshiji!

Answer (score 1):

Another option for internationalized table headings is the [table_for gem](https://github.com/hunterae/table-for).

This will let you write erb code like:

```
<%= table_for @user do |table| %>
  <% table.column :current_sign_in_at %>
<% end %>
```